# How to stream data from Mongodb to Hadoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop and I started planning an application to analyze the data I have on three collections on Mongodb combined, I tried to search something like the `Mongodb river for elasticsearch` but I didn't find a way to stream the data to Hbase or HDFS, I found Sqoop and Flume, but I don't know if this is the same I was looking for
The way I see, it will be like `http api  -> something here -> Hadoop storage`. Is there something which can do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Streaming Assembly,

The streaming assembly lets you write MapReduce jobs in languages like Python, Ruby, and JavaScript instead of Java, making it easy for developers that are familiar with MongoDB and popular dynamic programing languages to leverage the power of Hadoop.

For more info [visit](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/24610529795/hadoop-streaming-support-for-mongodb).

Comment: Thanks I will check it, btw, I'm also using Java so using it won't be a problem at all